# Misspoken English?

Tags: north-american-english

In a university course on anthro. linguistics I first heard the term 'east Tennessee mumble fuck' to describe the dialect spoken there which seemed to follow no rules in the world of linguistics. Is anyone here familiar with that term?

Secondly I grew up in Ypsilanti, MI aka Ypsi-tucky as most of the people there in the 40-50s- were from one county, Harlan County. The English spoken in town, by poor southern whites and blacks was once described as the one place in the US where the worst English language was spoken. Does anyone know the reference? It was published in a newspaper, probably back in the 50's.

Comment: What is your question? It's hard to imagine something that doesn't follow any grammar would classify as a language, anyway.

Comment: "The one place in the US where the worst English language was spoken" doesn't sound like a very scientific description. How would you objectively determine that? It seems weird to me that you heard this kind of thing in the context of linguistics, which is supposed to be the scientific study of language.

Comment: [Appalachian English](http://artsandsciences.sc.edu/engl/dictionary/), which is centered on East Tennessee and includes Harlan County, Kentucky, may diverge farther from 'Standard' English than any other US dialect, and it's popularly associated with a host of negative stereotypes. It would be sad to see those stereotypes entertained by linguistics scholars. [Disclaimer: my own speech derives from the fringe of southern Appalachia, and my wife is a graduate student teaching English in Knoxville.]

Comment: One question per question post please.

Comment: The rules are a mixture of Welsh, Scots, and Cherokee. Cherokee were taught English by Welsh Missionaries. Scots and Welsh were the early settlers in the region. The Cherokee remained the dominant culture in Cherokee lands until about the 1840's, and this included a lot of Europeans by then. Today, you would have difficulty finding someone who hadn't been exposed to radio or tv and Standard English. But even 30 years ago, there were communities that still lived apart. An economy based on moonshine, weed, bear parts, ginseng, and dog breeding (Rotts and Dobermans) tends to keep things insular.

Comment: @PhilSweet Interesting - [(this article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appalachian_English) says "Native American influences in the Appalachian dialect are virtually non-existent, the exception being place names". Where has Cherokee native language influenced the rules of English?

Comment: I was thinking of the sound of the dialect wrt the term mumblefuck. The Cherokee language lacks a whole raft of common English consonants, and that wasn't completely fixed by 200 years of missionaries teaching them English prior to the 1840's. Nasal vowels, dropped dipthongs, mumbled labial consonants, and mandatory grammatical aspect and modals. Overlay the map of inland dialect with the historical Cherokee lands, and listen to these contemporary Cherokee [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUYoRT2EA5Q), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saSSlSQwlwg)

Answer (score 3):

All humans who do not have a medical condition of some description, and who were not separated from other human beings during their childhood  speak their native language perfectly grammatically.

The prejudicial bigotry and general ignorance which certain groups of people are happy to overtly display in their description of non-prestige varieties of English, often surfaces in their description of those other varieties as ungrammatical. However, what these poor misguided souls do not understand is that grammar is just a description of the sophisticated mathematically complex rules, as yet poorly understood by scientists, which allow humans to seamlessly construct sentences without pausing to think about it.

It is not possible for a variety of a language to be "the worst English spoken". It is like saying that plant cells are better than animal cells. It doesn't make any sense.

I am also very interested in where this quote came from, as I am very interested in language variety prejudice and its history.

[If anyone can find this source, then I may be able to christen a new term, ***prescriptivist mumble fuckwit***, to describe its author.]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46215/discussion-on-answer-by-araucaria-misspoken-english).

Answer (score 1):

Re the first question: Maybe a riff on *East Bumblefuck*, which is a notional place, namely back of beyond, in the sticks, beyond the black stump, in the boonies, chez les schtis, etc. I suspect every language has an equivalent idiom to indicate some impossibly remote and backward place with none of the facilities to which you are accustomed.  By extension, your expression is a name for the inhabitants.  Personally, I think it's funny and may well be the creation of one the US's more colourful writers (don't know which).

Answer (score 0):

Just to sidestep the political issues around the correctness of dialects, and address the phrase "mumble fuck".

"Fuck" is a very versatile word which can be used colloquially in almost any possible way you could think of, usually either as an **intensifier** or to imply that something is **broken** or **bad**, or to generally insult the subject, or any combination of the above.

eg "that stupid fuck" -> "That stupid person, with added emphasis and insult."

I think "mumble fuck" is the same here.  It means the person mumbles, but also the mumbling is **really bad**, and breaks the communication process quite severely.  It may also be derived from the popular phrase "cluster fuck" which means "lots of things all going very badly wrong at the same time".